# Displaying Flash Objects in a Java generate window(JFrame)?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, actionscript

Hi I am developing an application for the web, desktop, mobile/tablet and TV which requires that third party swf files be loaded into my main Flash project. The problem that I am having is with the desktop application which is an AIR app that is going to be packaged as a native *.exe for Windows and a *.app file for Mac. I'd like to be able to create NativeWindow's but I seem to lose this functionality when I export to .exe or .app. I have also been working on a Java application which allows the control of Java lang Object's from Flash or JavaScript. This will allow me to create and control Frames through Flash code. I'd like to know if I can get a MovieClip or Sprite to display inside of a Java generated JFrame. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you:

```
package Components.FlashPlayer;

import Components.BCFrame;
import GUI.BCApp.DataTypeEnum;
import Logging.LogRunner;
import Properties.Basic.FlashPlayer_Prop;
import XMLProcessing.Helpers.XMLActionInfoHolder;
import XMLProcessing.XMLUtilities;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import java.io.*;

// import the JFlashPlayer package
import com.jpackages.jflashplayer.*;
import java.net.URL;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

/**
 * This class plays a flash video.
 * Create with help from: http://www.jpackages.com/jflashplayer , see the website
 * for a larger example of how to do more things with this code. I kind of modified
 * this to fit the current needs of the project. This works in conjunction with
 * dlls that need to go in the win32 folder. For linux/mac, look into the Apple
 * Java Quicktime API
 * @author dvargo
 */
public class FlashPlayer extends BCFrame implements FlashPanelListener {

    /**
     * handle to a FlashPanel instance
     */
    FlashPanel flashPanel;
    final Label currentFrameLabel = new Label("Frame: N/A");
    final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    JButton playButton,stopButton,forwardButton,rewindButton,backButton;
    JCheckBox loopCheckBox;
    private boolean isMovieSet = false;
    FrameMonitorThread fmt;
    boolean loop = false;
    boolean playOnStart = true;




    public enum Actions
    {
        Loop,
        Stop,
        Play
    }

    /**
     * Defualt constructor
     */
    public FlashPlayer()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Sets FlashPlayer to defualt size
     * @param x X position for the player
     * @param y Y position for the player
     * @param mainWindow Reference to the main window
     */
    public FlashPlayer(int x, int y, GUI.Window mainWindow) {
        this(x, y, 600, 400, mainWindow);
    }

    /**
     * Full consturtor
     * @param x X position for this player
     * @param y Y position for this player
     * @param w Width of the player
     * @param h Height of the player
     * @param mainWindow reference to the main window
     */
    public FlashPlayer(int x, int y, int w, int h, GUI.Window mainWindow) {
        super(x, y, w, h, mainWindow);
        initComponents();
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        createButtons();
        addCurrCompSetter(flashPanel,progressBar,currentFrameLabel,playButton,stopButton,forwardButton,rewindButton,loopCheckBox,backButton);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //                           
    private void initComponents() {

        videoPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        videoPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout videoPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(videoPanel);
        videoPanel.setLayout(videoPanelLayout);
        videoPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            videoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 381, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        videoPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            videoPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 247, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(videoPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(videoPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }//                         

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel videoPanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   




    /**
     * FlashPanelListener event method which receives FSCommand Flash events.
     *
     * You should use ExternalInterface.call instead of FSCommand
     * with the latest ActionScript version.  Older ActionScript versions
     * will only have access to FSCommand.
     */
    public void FSCommand(String command, String arg) {
        System.out.println("FlashPlayer (ignoring): FSCommand event received: " + command + " " + arg);
    }

    private void creatFlashPlayerWorker()
    {
         // add the FlashPanel to the frame
        this.getContentPane().add(flashPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        // specify the object for Flash ExternalInterface.call events to search for the called method on
        flashPanel.setFlashCallObject(this);

        // specify the FlashPanelListener in case a movie is using the older FSCommand event
        flashPanel.addFlashPanelListener(this);

        // specify variables for a flash movie which are available from the start of the
        // movie as long as this is called before the FlashPanel is visible
        flashPanel.setVariables("myGreeting=hi&myNumber=1&myVar=good%20job");

        isMovieSet = true;
        centerAndDisplay();
        fmt = new FrameMonitorThread(flashPanel);
        fmt.start();
        revalidate();
        if(!playOnStart)
        {
            stop();
        }
        setLoop(loop);
    }

    /**
     * Create a FlashPanel instance and add it to the frame
     */
    public void createFlashPanel(String url) {
        // install Flash 10 if Flash 6 or greater is not present
        //FlashPanel.installFlash("6");

        dataSource = dataSource.url;
        setData("Path",url.toString());
        String flashVersionRequired = "9";
        try
        { 
            FlashPanel.setRequiredFlashVersion(flashVersionRequired);
            flashPanel = new FlashPanel(new URL(url));//new File(flashFilePath));
        } 
        catch (JFlashLibraryLoadFailedException e)
        {
            exitError("A required library (DLL) is missing or damaged.");
        } 
        catch(JFlashInvalidFlashException e)
        {
            exitError("Required version " + flashVersionRequired + " of Flash is not installed. ");
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exitError("Something went wrong!\n" + e.toString());
        }

        creatFlashPlayerWorker();

    }

     /**
     * Create a FlashPanel instance and add it to the frame
     */
    public void createFlashPanel(File file) {
        // install Flash 10 if Flash 6 or greater is not present
        //FlashPanel.installFlash("6");

        //http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/SWF/flash_adpcm_testfiles/stereo_22.swf

        dataSource = dataSource.file;
        setData("Path",file.getAbsolutePath());
        String flashVersionRequired = "9";
        try
        {
            FlashPanel.setRequiredFlashVersion(flashVersionRequired);
            flashPanel = new FlashPanel(file);//new File(flashFilePath));
        }
        catch (JFlashLibraryLoadFailedException e)
        {
            exitError("A required library (DLL) is missing or damaged.");
        }
        catch(JFlashInvalidFlashException e)
        {
            exitError("Required version " + flashVersionRequired + " of Flash is not installed. ");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exitError("Something went wrong!\n" + e.toString());
        }

        creatFlashPlayerWorker();
    }


    public boolean isMovieSet()
    {
        return isMovieSet;
    }

    public boolean isPlayOnStart()
    {
        return playOnStart;
    }

    public boolean isLoop()
    {
        return loop;
    }

    public void setPlayOnStart(boolean dis)
    {
        playOnStart = dis;
    }
    public void setIsLoop(boolean dis)
    {
        loop = dis;
    }



    /**
     * Select a different SWF file at remote url
     */
    public void setMovie(URL url)
    {
        if(!isMovieSet)
        {
            createFlashPanel(url.toString());
            return;
        }
        setData("Path",url.toString());
        dataSource = dataSource.url;
        flashPanel.setMovie(url);
    }

    /**
     * Select a different SWF file at remote url
     */
    public void setMovie(String url)
    {
        if(!isMovieSet)
        {
            createFlashPanel(url);
            return;
        }
        setData("Path",url);
        dataSource = dataSource.url;
        try
        {
            flashPanel.setMovie(new URL(url));
            revalidate();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LogRunner.dialogMessage(this.getClass(),"Could not play Flash Movie at " + url);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Select a different SWF file on local machine
     */
    public void setMovie(File file)
    {

        setData("Path",file.getAbsolutePath()); //setting this to absolute path might cause a problem
        dataSource = dataSource.file;
        try
        {
            if(isMovieSet)
            {
                flashPanel.setMovie(file);
            }
            else
            {
                createFlashPanel(file);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           LogRunner.dialogMessage(this.getClass(),"Could not play Flash Movie at " + file);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to play.
     */
    public void play()
    {
        flashPanel.play();
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to stop playing.
     */
    public void stop()
    {
        flashPanel.stop();
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to go back one frame.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     */
    public void rewind()
    {
        rewind(1);
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to go back x number of frames.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     * @param numberOfFrames The number of frames to rewind
     */
    public void rewind(int numberOfFrames)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
        {
            flashPanel.back();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to go forward 1 frame.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     */
    public void forward()
    {
        forward(1);
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to go forward x number of frame.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     */
    public void forward(int numberOfFrames)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
        {
            flashPanel.forward();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to rewind to the first frame.
     * This will also stop the movie if it was playing.
     */
    public void goBackToBegining()
    {
        flashPanel.rewind();
    }

    /**
     * Select and set the flash movie background color.
     */
    public void backgroundAction(Color c)
    {
        flashPanel.setBackground(c);
    }

    /**
     * Instruct the flash movie to loop or not.
     */
    void setLoop(boolean loop) {
        flashPanel.setLoop(loop);
    }


    /**
     * Define some buttons to demonstrate JFlashPlayer functionality
     */
    void createButtons() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        playButton = new JButton("Play");
        playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                play();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(playButton);
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Pause");
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                stop();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(stopButton);
        backButton = new JButton("Back");
        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                goBackToBegining();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(backButton);
        forwardButton = new JButton("Forward");
        forwardButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                forward();
            }
        });
        //buttonPanel.add(forwardButton);
        rewindButton = new JButton("Rewind");
        rewindButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                rewind();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(rewindButton);

        loopCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Loop");
        loopCheckBox.setSelected(true);
        loopCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                setLoop(loopCheckBox.isSelected());
            }
        });

        progressBar.setVisible(true);

        buttonPanel.add(progressBar);

        for (int i = 0; i  screenSize.height) {
            frameSize.height = screenSize.height;
        }
        if (frameSize.width > screenSize.width) {
            frameSize.width = screenSize.width;
        }
        //this.setLocation((screenSize.width - frameSize.width) / 2,
        //      (screenSize.height - frameSize.height) / 2);
        this.setVisible(true);
        //this.toFront();
    }



    @Override
    protected void createProperties()
    {
        properties = new FlashPlayer_Prop(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void action(Enum a)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Enum convertStringToActionEnumValue(String in) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void build(HashMap theDictionary, String filePath, String DataSource, ArrayList actions)
    {
        if(DataSource.equals(DataTypeEnum.url.toString()))
            {
                createFlashPanel((String) theDictionary.get("Path"));
                setDataSource(DataTypeEnum.url);
            }
            else
            {
                String theFile = XMLUtilities.parseFilePath(filePath) + File.separator + (String) theDictionary.get("Path");
                createFlashPanel(new File(theFile));
                setDataSource(DataTypeEnum.file);
            }
        playOnStart = Boolean.parseBoolean(theDictionary.get("PlayOnStart"));
        loop = Boolean.parseBoolean(theDictionary.get("Loop"));
        //add actions to the component
        setActions(XMLUtilities.getActions(this, actions));
    }

    @Override
    public Element extractData(Document dom)
    {
        setData("PlayOnStart",Boolean.toString(playOnStart));
        setData("Loop", Boolean.toString(loop));
        return super.extractData(dom);
    }

    @Override
    public File[] extractFiles(String filePath)
    {
        File retVal = new File(getData("Path"));
        if(retVal == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        setData("Path","files" + File.separator + retVal.getName());
        return new File[]{retVal};
    }

    @Override
    public void drag(File[] theFiles)
    {
     //if they dragged a one file in
        if(theFiles.length == 1)
        {
            //try and set it as the image of this component
            setMovie(new File(theFiles[0].getAbsolutePath()));
        }
        //they dragged multiple files in
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < theFiles.length; i++)
            {
                int location = (i * 5) % mainWindow.getComponentContentPane().getHeight();

                FlashPlayer temp = new FlashPlayer(location,location , mainWindow);
                temp.createFlashPanel(new File(theFiles[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                mainWindow.getCurrPage().addComponent(temp);
                mainWindow.getCurrPage().loadPage();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BCFrame copy(int x, int y) {
        try
        {
            FlashPlayer clone = new FlashPlayer(x,y,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),mainWindow);
            clone.setTitleBarVisible(this.isTitleBarRemoved());
            clone.setActions(this.getActions());
            if(dataSource == dataSource.file)
            {
                clone.setMovie(new File(this.getData("Path")));
            }
            else
            {
                clone.setMovie(this.getData("Path"));
            }
            clone.setPlayOnStart(isPlayOnStart());
            clone.setIsLoop(isLoop());
            return clone;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LogRunner.dialogMessage(this.getClass(),"Cant clone this compoenent");

        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Thread to poll the current frame of the flash movie to be displayed
     */
    class FrameMonitorThread extends Thread {

        FlashPanel flashPanel;

        FrameMonitorThread(FlashPanel fp) {
            flashPanel = fp;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (flashPanel != null) {
                    final long currentFrame = flashPanel.getCurrentFrame();
                    final long totalFrames = flashPanel.getTotalFrames();
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            double cf = currentFrame;
                            double tf = totalFrames;
                            double result = cf/tf;
                            int percent = (int)(100 * result);
                            try{progressBar.setValue(percent);}catch(Exception e){}
                            currentFrameLabel.setText("Frame: " + currentFrame + "/" + totalFrames);

                        }
                    });
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks whterer the dlls that flash player needs are in their correct spot
     * @return True if all the dlls could be found, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean checkDlls()
    {
        String systemFolder = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\";
        String [] dlls = new String[]{"atl2k.dll","atl98.dll","jflash.dll"};
        for(String x : dlls)
        {
            if(!new File(systemFolder + x).exists())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }


}
```